# Database relationship modeling - sqlite

Tags: database, uml, tool-uml

I have a database with several tables in it stored in sqlite.
I'm looking for a product or piece of code that will turn this into a relationship diagram for me - it doesn't have to be a specific model, such as UML etc. Just anything that works - Does anyone know of an available product that can plug directly into the sqlite database and populate the tables and fields on a graph for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try on line modeling tool [SQLauncher](http://www.sqlauncher.com). It is simple to use and allows off line mode. Also sqlauncher allows to create ASCII view of each model entity.

Answer (score 2):

Navicat for SQLite can do this ( the Enterprise version is the only version that supports this, via http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_sqlite/sqlite_feature.html )

It has a model tool but in order to use it, it took me a little bit to understand the UI:

Make the connection to your database.
Double click on the connection.  Right click on main(usually that is the database), and click "Reverse Database to Model..." from the menu.

Opening the Model tool directly and trying to do this seems to be impossible.

I don't work for them.. I bought it on sale at some point for around $25.